# Tableau - Filter not working appropriately

Tags: tableau-api

I am using tableau to create a bullet graph as follows.  The value is displayed correctly as follows.

[Bullet Graph 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdiBC.png)

However, when I move the 'Year' variable to Filter, the 'Sales' value changes as follows.

[Bullet Graph 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2yDd.png)

I cannot figure out the reason.  As the 'Sales' variable is from another Table ('Orders') shown in the image, I suspect there is a problem in the linkage between that Table and Table 'Sales Target'.

I appreciate if someone can advise me on this issue.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you please upload this file on drive and share the link?

Comment: Hi,

Please see the 2 excel files as well as the word file listing the tasks to be completed.  Thanks. 

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1C7ZeLQeUtfegFV3Sj3RA-XzO9lirbs8V?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

All things being equal it seems the **graph is visually only showing 1 year** (correctly) **GIVEN** that there appears to only 1 year selected in the filter for 2014 (*right-hand bar*).

This seems reasonable to me. If you require the column to still show the different years along the `x-axis`, then hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> (or <kbd>CMD</kbd>) before dragging the year to the filter pane *so that it creates a copy.*

That way it will still show the break-down by year(s) since the pill remains in the columns shelf, and will prevent the values doing a roll-up (aggregate) if multiple years are selected.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [This Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to format your posts.